# How to install Octave in Scientific Linux 6.5?

Tags: software-installation, scientific-linux, octave

I am following the [installation instruction](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_GNU/Linux#Red_Hat) for Scientific Linux on Ocatve website:

```
# wget http://url/to/latest/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
# yum localinstall epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
```

Then I type

```
# sudo yum install octave-forge
```

It shows:

```
  No package octave-forge available.
```

How can I install Octave in Scientific Linux 6.5?

Answer (score 1):

Those instructions appear to be obsolete, perhaps because the version of Octave in EPEL 6 is too old to run Octave Forge now. Octave 3.4.3 is in EPEL at the moment, but the current version of Octave is 3.8.1.

I came to this conclusion by installing octave from EPEL, then attempting to install several Octave packages:

```
$ octave
octave:1> pkg install -forge bim
  bim needs octave >= 3.6.0
  ...etc...
octave:1> pkg install -forge optim
  optim needs octave >= 3.6.0
  ...etc...
octave:1> pkg install -forge io
  bim needs octave >= 3.8.0
  ...etc...
```

Apparently, if you want to use Octave Forge, you need to install from source, rather than from EPEL.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please type the specific commandlines which I need to install octave3.8.1 in Scientific Linux6.5?